# Hive Insert query on EMR just keeps running for more then 17 hours

Tags: hive, hiveql, amazon-emr, metastore

Background:

- EMR 5.4 cluster of 2 nodes(master+slave).
- Supplied the external Hive metastore details during the setup.
- The Hive warehouse has been set on S3.
- I am using spark 2.1 to process the file and create a staging table.
- Once the staging table is ready I am trying to load that data in to hive table using hive.

Problem: The insert statement which usually runs about 7-10 mins on other cluster(outside AWS) is taking to run forever on the EMR cluster. I was able to query the staging table that was created by spark from hive. The following are the statements that I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE Test1(
column1 string ,
column2 string,
column3 double)
PARTITIONED BY (Date_1 date)

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE Test1 PARTITION(date_1)
SELECT
column1,
column2,
column3,
date_1
FROM Test1_stag
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did u get a solution to this?

Comment: No .I could not find a working solution.